# cannot handle 409 response code in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When i trying this piece of code, that is working in the case of 201 status code.....

```
resource_m = RestClient::Resource.new Rails.application.config.sta+"/mov"
resource_m = resource_m.post  @hash.to_json,  :content_type => :json, :accept =>:json
puts "code...#{resource_m.code}"

case resource_m.code
when 201
  respond_to do |format|
    @noticec =  {:name =>"Successfully",:code => "201"}
    format.json  { render :json => @noticec }
  end
when 409
  respond_to do |format|
    @noticec =  {:name =>"already exists",:code => "409" }
    format.json  { render :json => @noticec }
  end   

when 401
  respond_to do |format|
      @noticec =  {:name =>"Error",:code => "401" }
      format.json  { render :json => @noticec }
   end
else
  respond_to do |format|
      @noticec =  {:name =>"Something went wrong" }
      format.json  { render :json => @noticec }
   end

end
```

But if the response code from server is 409, rails giving an error Completed 500 Internal
  Server Error in 1370ms
  ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template).
**But when i try this in REST-CLIENT i could see the status code is 409 conflict.**. i cannot take that response code in controller.

Answer (score 0):

IIRC `resource.post` raises an exception on 4xx, 5xx reponses. I am sure about ruby's http client and quite sure about RestClient, but it is easy to *fix*

```
begin
  resource_m = resource_m.post  @hash.to_json,...
rescue 
  puts_or_debug
end
```

Comment: I have try that with begin rescue, now i got that code  in rescue
   rescue => e
     puts "error.....#{e.message}"     
   end
error.....409 Conflict